# Python: Perforce client error while remotely executing command

Tags: python, ssh, perforce, paramiko

On Linux Machine **A**, i have a script running which is supposed to ssh into Linux Machine **B**, sync the p4 workspace on **B** and then execute a piece of code.

I've set up Perforce on **B** and I'm able to manually execute `p4 client` and other commands on **B** and they work.

However, when i attempt to do the same thing while sshing from Machine A, i get the following error:

> Perforce client error:
>       Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
>       TCP connect to perforce:1666 failed.
>       Temporary failure in name resolution

Here's my piece of code:

```
def ssh_connect(ip,user,pwd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=pwd)  
    return ssh


def execute_command(device_details, command):
    try:
        ip = device_details.get('ip')
        username = device_details.get('username')
        password = device_details.get('password')
        ssh_ns_obj = ssh_connect(ip, username, password)

        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_ns_obj.exec_command(command)
        print ssh_stdout.read()
        print ssh_stderr.read()
        print ssh_stdin.read()
        return ssh_stdout.read()
    except Exception as e:
        print_exception_details()      


perforce_sync_command = "cd /root/hello/;chmod -R 444 *;p4 sync ...;chmod -R 755 *"
output = execute_command(device_details, perforce_sync_command)
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce needs a set of environment variables to run - on ssh, the environment variables were not visible on the ssh session.

To solve this, i edited the file `/etc/environment` and added the `P4PORT, P4USER, P4CLIENT, P4PASSWD` vars in the file.

Comment: A more standard way of doing this would be to either use the `p4 set` command (which writes to your `.p4enviro` file) or to specify the `-p PORT -u USER -c CLIENT` flags within the script.